# Reflection::hasMethod vs. method_exists performance

Tags: php

From performance point of view should I choose:

```
$className = 'Foobar';
$methodName = 'method';
```

This

```
$Reflected = new ReflectionClass($className);
$result = $Reflected->hasMethod($methodName);
```

over

```
$result = method_exists($className,$method);
```

And why?

For this case I'm not using any other properties or methods of ReflectionClass.

Comment: Reflection is always slower than some native PHP method for checking whether the method is defined. Not sure how bad it is in PHP but in Java reflection is slow like hell... And You can always do some own debugging... Do two loops of 10000 repeatings in which within the first loop measure the time for reflection and within the second measure the time for `method_exists`... Then compare and You are done...

Comment: Why do you not just measure which is faster?

Comment: For single check it's overkill using ReflectionClass. Use it when you make a complicated check on class

Comment: Building test setups with simple loops is fun when you have the time, but usually you miss something if you are not paying attention for example is loops equivalent to benching with apache ab etc... I believe someone has already made some tests on the subject and I would like to see the benchmarks.

Comment: I know this is a relatively old question but I had the need to respond because some answers that have been given might lead you into thinking that the code that runs the fastest is the best code. I believe Donald Knuth summed it it rather nicely "premature optimization is the root of all evil". I don't know if the method_exists function is slower or faster than using reflections but I would not look at reflection as being slow or evil, it's simply a tool which you can use when you need it. I wouldn't worry too much about the reflection speed unless your using it inside a large loop.

Comment: @C.A.Harris I wouldn't ask if I wasn't using it inside a huge loop containing thousands of objects having varying classes. Readabilitywise I would prefer method_exists since only thing I was interested in was if certain method existed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I measured it with 1,000,000 loops. It may be not representative.

Needed 21 seconds:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($module);
$reflector->hasMethod('getDecryptedId'))
```

Needed 1.2 seconds:

```
method_exists($module, 'getDecryptedId')
```

So **method_exists is 17.5 times faster**. This only is interresting, if you do massive use of it.

Comment: It might be interesting that - given you already got a ReflectionClass in context anyway - hasMethod is slightly faster then method_exists:
method_exists: 2.242s
hasMethod: 1.806s
(Both for 10kk iterations with php 5.6.7 in a vagrant vm)

Answer (score 1):

I measured a few different metrics:

- setup reflection outside the loop
- where the method exists
- where the method does not exist
- where the method is on the parent class

I did 500,000 loops on my 2015 MBP and the results were very similar.

- `method_exists` was around 3.4 - 3.5 seconds
- `hasMethod` was around 3.7 - 3.8 seconds

So not much difference depending on the position / existence of the method, and reflection was slightly slower, at 8%.

If I needed more info reflection would be the way to go, but for a simple check, `method_exists` has the edge.